# BASH - search for file with a specifc pattern that exist in directories with specific pattern -RECURSIVELY

Tags: bash, recursion

i asked to write script that searching recursively for files that match to the pattern "*.foo" BUT the only files which exist in directories that match to the same pattern "*.foo".
i tried: 
script name : search_for_foo

```
function foo_search {
 while read line; do
    echo "$line”   
 done < "$1"
 }
 for file in ${*:1}; do
  if [[ $file == *.foo* ]]; then
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
       foo_search $file
       fi
       if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
       search_for_foo $file/*
       fi
    fi
    done <"$1"
```

it has to work this way : ./search_for_foo --some_file--

thanks in advance

Comment: use the find command.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
find -path "*foo/*/foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location=$1
pattern=$2

dir=$(find $location -type d -name "*.$pattern")

ls -lrt $dir|grep ^- |awk '{print $NF}'
```

run like ./script.sh /location/directory/ pattern